# How to search contain text in column and return data in new column using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have an Excel file with many columns, and I need to search and get data that contains a search text and return it to a new column. My data as below.

**Column A:**

```
xxxxx\detail\A1\yyyy
aaaaa\detail\A2\zzzz
A3
```

I want the following result.

**Column B:**

```
detail\A1
detail\A2
A3
```

My code is below, but it returns the position of the search text instead.

```cs
$File = "C:\\Testt.xlsx"
$SearchString = "detail\" + "*"+ "\"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $($Workbook.Sheets.Count() + 1); $i++) {
    $Range = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($i).Range("A:A")
    $Target = $Range.Find($SearchString)
    $First = $Target
    do {
        Write-Host "$i $($Target.AddressLocal())"
        $Target = $Range.FindNext($Target)
    } while ($Target -ne $null -and $Target.AddressLocal() -ne $First.AddressLocal())
}
$Excel.Quit()
```